# jquery validation which allow dot and colon after two digit

Tags: javascript, regex

```
$('#total_duration').keyup(function(event) {
  this.value = this.value
  .replace(/[^\d:]/g, '')             // numbers and decimals only
  .replace(/(^[\d]{2})[\d]/g, '$1')   // not more than 2 digits at the beginning
  .replace(/(\::*)\s:/g, '$1')         // decimal can't exist more than once
  .replace(/(\:[\d]{2})./g, '$1');    // not more than 4 digits after decimal         
});
```

This allow colon after two digit like 11:12 but i want dot(.)  like 11.12 also in pattern

fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/8dLb06je/

Comment: Nothing to do with jQuery, everything to do with RegExp.

Comment: please share pattern which has to write

Comment: Show your string and expected result

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8dLb06je/ this is fiddle link